# Streming of audio .wav files from http server to ios clients

Tags: ios, streaming, wav

I am working on an http server where lots of audio files in .wav format get uploaded which are of less than 1 min. I need to provide my ios clients with a solution to stream files instead of downloading them . 
I have tried following approaches : -

1. creating .m3u files manually which contain these .wav files , but they donot play on ios but plays fine on vlc
2. using lame to convert .wav into .mp3 , then using ffmpeg to convert .mp3 into MPEG-2 stream audio.ts file . Then i used segmenter tool to break audio.ts into different chunks and create .m3u8 file which is played fine on quicktime on mac .

But the glitch is that i could not find a linux tool for segmenter .

Now , my worry is , whether i am using the right approach or should i use some existing streaming server like darwin server ? Please let me know the pros and cons of different approaches and wht parameters should i look for before using any of them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is good. HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) is the best way to get streaming audio on the iPhone.

HLS is interesting in that it doesn't need a specific server to be used. A normal HTTP server will work (Apache, lighttpd, nginx etc.). Then you need a segmenter. A quick google revealed [M3U8 Segmenter](http://m3u8-segmenter.inodes.org/), which appears to be what you want (I haven't used it myself).

Comment: i am not able to compile this segmenter on linux . Lots of errors . Is there a step by step procedure to do same

Comment: What distro of linux are you on?